# Reindex process hangs and blocks website

Tags: magento2, database, reindex

I have a problem in my Magento 2 (version 2.3.4) shop that reindex process sometimes runs indefinitely and brings the whole site down (502 nginx error or timeouts).

I noticed on the DB level, that in such a case, virtually all queries are blocked because they are waiting for table locks. Only a single query by the reindex process is running, but never finishes. Here is a listing of queries running during such a situation:

```
mysql> select id, db,command, state, left(info,100) from information_schema.processlist;
+---------+----------+---------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id      | db       | command | state                           | left(info,100)                                                                                       |
+---------+----------+---------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 8165312 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_bb745c5e7f2610352c060b36709e54032aaf8c15` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165311 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_f91821f67870f011d3f8a38e9908c3235747584b` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165289 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_2d834f92e9b71a91a5c2520192539cd38560d22c` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165288 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_abca7e583ce39ed454be82b78bdc29b389a4ee74` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165260 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_18b43873915bfb0015033be4ee261cae3e897dee` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165244 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_d661c3a49566eb6a35f5043718ae99047b176662` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165217 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_da8bbd709684db07102be86caeae8712790bb37e` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165261 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_dd977f7939670fc3eb19c6b5c89be77b8bba52b1` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165259 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_28d513e50adac3dd498f9d4087f648cf73ad8e9d` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165199 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_438c79baa1470f9f4e435b50046e5f65c06c58dc` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165153 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_a12ea76415ddb9a0179ed2dbdf48b88b9b3132e6` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165020 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | RENAME TABLE catalog_product_index_price TO catalog_product_index_price_outdated,catalog_product_ind |
| 8165251 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_32a2d91876b5b4fa38eb6f3773074ad9d4854390` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165247 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_be2127ec0bdd7a56beb8e59fdc5a5a1164ef3bbb` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165017 | magento2 | Sleep   |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 8164957 | magento2 | Query   | Filling schema table            | select id, db,command, state, left(info,100) from information_schema.processlist                     |
| 8165240 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_1ca9188823f3af39434548117fde49aacd9cf7c1` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165226 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_94f703629874d7a4b20c58a4d863266d1f7f6ba4` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165219 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_0e88fc675d33b150e9cc7718cb70820ca88bc80c` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165210 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_b6f322baae91918f8b91001156a149072e904f41` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165206 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_e62016ea2ea8631932f1dd5643c93d81922c4949` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165194 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_e69208892fe0386e6baff43b2ff244d49fa6eb4c` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165202 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_3a805f9691560f0b892b4da18c0041277ce1b99e` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165188 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_c97916867bdb1e1427abeac76cee57a164038c50` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165179 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_2b4ee30f3f92d09e3843e9b6a65f31751d180770` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165173 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_860d16fe274ea842d23c9bd73c74fef4abf5ebc4` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165167 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_a963adc29cdca3c797b041e777010031d3eb5fc6` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165155 | magento2 | Query   | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_895b1ef14a24275b53c171d0d2bb5cc94c1ae4b1` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165147 | magento2 | Query   | Sending data                    | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_cb95277cd601e038246f880aca3c4f1113f61a70` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
| 8165142 | magento2 | Query   | Sending data                    | INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_dee736e9ad4f2d069f5750cd5411f566775e42cb` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `cata |
+---------+----------+---------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Only the last 2 queries are actually running, but they never finish. When I forcably kill the reindex process on the shell, those 2 queries keep running, but never finish, and the situation is not resolved.

I have to `KILL` these specific queries in MySQL, only then the website responds again.

I noticed that the queries blocking the process are always `INSERT IGNORE INTO temp_XXX` queries that build stock or price indexes, like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp_cb95277cd601e038246f880aca3c4f1113f61a70` SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store3` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=3 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=17036
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1` ON `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id` AND `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1`.`attribute_id` = '18249' AND `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1`.`store_id` = '3' AND `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1`.`value` IN (2894)
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1__stock` ON `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1`.`source_id` = `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1__stock`.`product_id` AND `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1__stock`.`website_id` = 0 AND `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1__stock`.`stock_id` = 1 AND `layered_nav_f_filter_typ_1__stock`.`stock_status` = 1
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel` ON `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id` AND `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel`.`attribute_id` = '18253' AND `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel`.`store_id` = '3' AND `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel`.`value` IN (3044)
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel__stock` ON `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel`.`source_id` = `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel__stock`.`product_id` AND `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel__stock`.`website_id` = 0 AND `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel__stock`.`stock_id` = 1 AND `layered_nav_f_filter_kabelmantel__stock`.`stock_status` = 1
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1` ON `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id` AND `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1`.`attribute_id` = '18251' AND `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1`.`store_id` = '3' AND `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1`.`value` IN (3009,3004)
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1__stock` ON `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1`.`source_id` = `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1__stock`.`product_id` AND `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1__stock`.`website_id` = 0 AND `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1__stock`.`stock_id` = 1 AND `layered_nav_f_filter_paarzahl_1__stock`.`stock_status` = 1 WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)
```

(the select part of this query runs in 0ms and returns ~1000 records)

I asked this question also on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/posts/1041808/edit), because I was first looking for a MySQL related issue. But maybe there is a magento specific solution to this, too.

For Magento related information: There are around 6500 products in the shop, 3 store views. I don't use magento's stock keeping, and have my own price calculation module (hence I think that price index and stock index are not relevant for my website). Products are updated on demand via a custom importer. Reindex should be triggered by cron, but since I regularily run into this problem, I deactivated the cron, and do it manually / directly after product update, where I babysit the process to intervine in case the problem occurs (which is most of the time).

This problem can also occur in times where I take the website offline and nothing runs except a single reindex process (and cron, which does however not trigger another reindex)

Has anybody encountered similar problems, and found a solution for this. Is there something I can tune in my DB setup?

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: Version 2.3.4. Added it to the question

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?